# Import 3 SDKs, get error: Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar

Tags: java, android, jar, facebook-android-sdk, android-2.2-froyo

I create an Android-application.
Have imported all my SDKs (GoogleSDK, FacebookSDK, AppCompatSDK)

Right-click on my ***project -> properties -> Android -> Add*** my 3 SDKs.
Press on Apply and get this error:

> **Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but
>   not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at
>   this time). All versions of the libraries must be the same at this
>   time.**

What should I do?
The project isnt red, there is nothing red in *Order and Export, & Libraries*

( This app will work from API 8 & above )

P.S
*If you know any link to a good tutorial there it shows how to make loginbutton for FacebookSDK 3.5, login and go back to a new Activity would be nice. Just login & signout, nothing more.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For different versions of android-support-v4.jar file, do following steps:-

1. Go to libs folder of any of the most recent project (which contains latest jar file)
2. Right click on android-support-v4.jar  file and copy it.
3. Paste the copied file in other project which are showing error.
4. Clean the project and run it.

For integration of any of the SDKs, if you are adding a jar file, just copy the jar in your libs folder and Right click the project > Select Properties > Libraries tab > Add jars > Navigate to your project's libs folder, select the SDK's jar you want to add and you are done.

Clean the build and run.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just need to know this to, so I'm clear of what I'm doing.

Instead of right-click my project -> properties -> Android and Add my FacebookSDK, GoogleSDk & ActionCompatSDK, I can instead import theirs jar-file to my project?

Comment: You can either add a project as a library or as a jar, whichever you think is comfortable. For adding jars, you need to add resources too to the source folder and as a library you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks. You saved a lot of my time :)

Comment: Note: This works great with the Navigator view, but not with Package Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I your setup should be:

```
Workspace
  |
  |-Library Project 1 (FacebookSDK)
  |---|...
  |---|libs
  |-----|-android-support.jar
  |-Library Project 2 (GoogleSDK)
  |---|...
  |---|libs
  |-----|-android-support.jar
  |-MainApplication Project
  |---|...
  |---|libs
  |-----|-android-support.jar
```

Make sure that for each project, the android-support.jar is included in `Android Private Libraries` folder:

- right click on `{{project name}}`, select `Properties` from the menu;
- a `Properties for {{project name}}` window appears;
- select `Java Build Path` from the left;
- select `Libraries` tab;
- make sure you have the jar in `Android Private Libraries`, if not add it;
- select `Order and Export` tab;
- make sure the checkbox for `Android Private Libraries` is selected.

The last think you should check is that you have the same version of the `jar` in all your projects. do the following for all your projects:

- right click on `{{project name}}`, select `Android Tools/Add support library...`;

The same thing applies to all jars, not only the support one. You have to add it to the build path and make sure you have the same version of it in all your projects.

Let me know if you got it working.

Comment: Thank you so much. So every SDK I have should have the same "android-support.jar" in their own iibs. And what with the other jar files that FacebookSDk, GoogleSDK have? just import it as jar to the project like Bette Devine said?